# Intersection of two non-ASCII string sets

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, intersection

I have two text files uploading them in [here](http://textuploader.com/5eyn3) and [here](http://textuploader.com/5eyn8). each row is a phrase and its count in both files. I want to find their intersections. I wrote the code as below in `python 2.7`:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
osool=[]
osoolCount=[]
eslah=[]
eslahCount=[]
for line in open("osool.txt"):
    osool.append(str(line.split(',')[0]).decode('utf-8'))
    osoolCount.append(int(line.split(',')[1]))
for line in open("eslah.txt"):
    eslah.append(str(line.split(',')[0]).decode('utf-8'))
    eslahCount.append(int(line.split(',')[1]))
intersection=list(set(eslah) & (set(osool)))
for i in intersection:
    print i
```

The problem is the `intersection` does not include all similar phrases. For examples, `ادب_مرد_به_ز_دولت_اوست` is in both text files, but when I print intersections, it is not in there!

What is the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is most lines in both files contain a number and comma before the text that you want to compare. In your example, the line `ادب_مرد_به_ز_دولت_اوست` shows up in `osool` file with extra text prepended: `5,` and in `eslah` file with `25,`, so the `intersection` operation will not consider those lines similar. With that, if you strip off the number and `,` at the beginning of each line I get `21 intersections` of text between both files. Is that correct? If so, I'll gladly post my code in an answer for it.

Comment: You can check my script [here](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/WYO0wffbO59larK6ML1E/)

Comment: @downshift thanks for your response. I split lines to numbers and strings. Thus, `5` and `25` are appended in `osoolCount` and `eslahCount`. Also, phrases are appended in `osool` and `eslah` lists. The count and phrases are completely splited.  Besides, intersections are about `41` not `21`.